# How can I modify a Gmail account to forward an email that comes in with additional parameters?

Tags: gmail, automation

Say my Gmail account gets an email. How can I make it so that any email that comes to my Gmail account automatically forwards to another email `bob@gmail.com` with ADDITIONAL parameters in the body of the email? Do I have to use a PHP script with IMAP or can I do this with Gmail alone?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "additional parameters"?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write some code to accomplish your goal. Your app will log in to the Gmail server, grab all the new messages, alter them to add whatever parameters you want, and then send them off to the new address.

I've done something similar using C# in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with directly from Gmail's interface. You will have to add a forwarding address and then you can create a filter that will forward only specific mails that contains some words in the body or whatever else you want.

[image: add forwarding email to gmail]

By enabling the forwarding address it doesn't mean that all your mails will be forwarded. You'll have to do that in order to have the option during the creation of the filter.

Comment: I believe OP wants to append information to the messages that get forwarded.